# Why does my BaseClass:Method code compile (with single colon)?

Tags: c++

I ran into the following code that spits a segmentation fault. Then I realized I typed Base:hello() instead of Base::hello, but it surprises me that the single colon code would compile. How is Base:hello() a valid expression?

```
class Base {
    public:
    virtual void hello() {
      cout << "Hello" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
 void hello() override {
   Base:hello();  // why does this compile?
 }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Base:` is parsed as a [label](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Labels), which can be used as the target of a [`goto` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto). So this is equivalent to just calling `hello()` and that, of course, will give you infinite recursion and a stack overflow.

Comment: I always like to use the example of why `http://example.com` is valid C++ code. Hey, you can add URLs to C++ files ;-) It's just a label + a comment.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, but only one `http` and one `https` URL per function ;)

Comment: Sure, but still nifty ;)